# What files should be stored in source control when using nuget packages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm a little confused as to which files should be stored into TFS (source control) so that other developers can get the project and have all the nuget package dependencies be automatically loaded.

It doesn't make sense to have to store the large dll's but whenever someone at work uses nuget it doesn't always 'just work'.

Is there a clear best practise to ensure when someone sets up a new computer they get pull down the files from TFS and the nuget files will be downloaded into their project?

Comment: visual studio knows how to properly add the nuget references so that it only stores what it needs to in source control. To see how this works, you could create a new solution, add the solution to source control, and add a nuget package. Then observe what files / folders visual studio saves to TFS.